# Iterating through object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, iteration

I have a set of properties inside of a javasript object.

```
    var leanToolButtonStatus = {
    FiveSStatus:0,
    SmallLotStatus:0,
    SmedStatus:0,
    QualityStatus:0,
    CellsStatus:0,
    CrossTrainStatus:0,
    SelfDirectedStatus:0,
    PMStatus:0,
    VendorStatus:0,
    SmallPurchaseStatus:0,
    NewEquipmentStatus:0,
    MarketStatus:0,
    KanbanStatus:0
}
```

Now I want to run a `for-loop` to iterate over that so I try:

```
  function loopThroughObject(){
    var iterationCounter = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x<1; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y<6; y++){
        switch(leanToolButtonStatus[iterationCounter]) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            }
        }
        iterationCounter++;
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number.
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

if the structure of your object is exactly like you added in your question, you wont need for loop, just access it as :

```
var leanToolButtonStatus = {
    FiveSStatus:0,
    SmallLotStatus:0,
    SmedStatus:0,
    QualityStatus:0,
    CellsStatus:0,
    CrossTrainStatus:0,
    SelfDirectedStatus:0,
    PMStatus:0,
    VendorStatus:0,
    SmallPurchaseStatus:0,
    NewEquipmentStatus:0,
    MarketStatus:0,
    KanbanStatus:0
};
console.log(leanToolButtonStatus["FiveSStatus"]);
```

if you dont know the key names. you can use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, as:

```
for(val in leanToolButtonStatus ) {
    console.log(leanToolButtonStatus[val]);
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to iterate through a loop in order for some some drawing placement to be handled. So therefore I wouldn't be able to call just the key. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tukajo in that case you can use for..in loop to iterate thru object key/values like the one added in answer

Answer (score 2):

It should work with this codesnippet:

```
for(key in list)
{
 var elementOfList = list[key];
}
```

key could be 'FiveSStatus' and elementOfList 0

Answer (score 1):

```
#1
for (var key in leanToolButtonStatus) {
   leanToolButtonStatus[key]
}

#2
Object.keys(leanToolButtonStatus).forEach(function (key) {
    leanToolButtonStatus[key]
});
```